# Creating a .wsp for SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I am migrating an existing SharePoint project from from SharePoint 2010 / Visual Studio 2010 to SharePoint 2013 / Visual Studio 2013. Previously I used WSPBuilder to build the .wsp file, but there appears to be issued using it with SharePoint 2013 since SP13 uses .net 4.0.

What alternatives do I have? I'm thinking I'll either need to modify wspbuilder's source to get it to work with SP13 projects or manually create the wsp with makecab.. but it would be nice if there was some plugin for this.

I've tried MSBuild ([How can I create a Sharepoint package (*.wsp) from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736513/how-can-i-create-a-sharepoint-package-wsp-from-command-line)) and I get 'no package found in project'.

Do I need to recreate this project from an empty SharePoint project?

Comment: I've found sharepoint.stackexchange.com to also be a helpful resource for SharePoint.

Comment: Ever since SP 2010 you can just use visual studio to build/deploy WSP packages.  Why do you want to use a plugin at all when you can just do that?

Comment: this project pre-dates sp2010. that is why i'm asking "Do I need to recreate this project from an empty SharePoint project?" -- my point is, is this something I'd need to do to take advantage of build/deploy within VS..?

Comment: it was fine with sp2010 because WSPBuilder was still compatible with sp2010. it is not compatible with sp2013.

Comment: @mikey thanks, I'm posting the question there.